# How old is Ned Flanders' Grandmother?

Tags: the-simpsons

Grandma Flanders must be pretty old (and possibly dead?) but considering Ned's own advanced age (possibly) she must be very old indeed. I can't find any direct evidence for anyone's age, except for Ned saying he's 60 and having living parents.

Comment: The characters on The Simpson's do not age. Take for example Bart and Lisa who are known to be 10 and 8 years old respectively and have been for the entire run of the series. Therefore, if Ned is 60, he has always been and will always be 60 and his parents are more than likely in their 80s. My own parents are in their 60's and my grandparents are in their 80s.

Comment: I'm too lazy to do the maths but the Simpsons is on right now -- a 'back in the day' episode in which Bart and Lisa are around but younger, Ned's grandmother dies. The same day she says she's 100. There are issues to work out with that what with the timeline and such but I hope its a springboard for someone who does have the effort and resources at hand to turn it into a fully worked out answer :P edit: same episode states Bart is 4 and Lisa is 2. Enough there that it wouldn't be too hard -- In that case I'll do up a real answer when I get home unless someone beats me to it hehe

Comment: I assume the title is wrong and you're asking about Ned's **mother**?

Comment: https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Grandma_Flanders

Answer (score 2):

### Apparently 100

As seen in the clip below, she states she has just turned 100.

> NED: Now, sir, don't you waffle on that brunch. Grandma Flanders can watch the kids.
>
> GRANDMA FLANDERS: Hello, Joe.
>
> HOMER: Doesn't know who I am... has trouble moving... I'd say we have ourselves babysitter.
>
> GRANDMA FLANDERS: **I just turned a hundred.**

Although she uses the wrong name, Ned doesn't correct this or the age she gives. It's possible that the age is wrong but, unless the character appears again with a definitive birth and/or death date, we may not know for certain.